# Divs not aligning properly on website (work fine in CodePen though)

Tags: html, css, alignment

My site consists of green boxes (divs) that are aligned side-by-side in rows.
There are 3 divs per row, and their heights are suppose to be the same.

Everything works perfectly except for some reason there are 3 divs **not** aligning properly at the bottom of the page.

The problem only occurs on my website though, but works fine in a CodePen for some reason. Can you pinpoint the problem?

[Here is my site](http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/index_main2.html) (scroll down to see problem)

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYXoYd)  (no issue for some reason)

and here is a screenshot showing the issue on my server:

[image]

The div's HTML is:

```
  <a href="http://www.Demo Demo/Land/details_land.html">
     <p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/5.jpg)"></p>
    <div> 

      <p class="titlebox">Sample Title Title Title</p>
      <p>Demo Demo</p>
      <p>Demo Demo</p>
    </div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    .mainbox {
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
  height: 4000px;
}
.mainbox a {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin: 0 0.5em 0;
width: 25%;
background: #A1F997;
box-shadow: 0 50px 0 #A1F997 , 0 100px #A1F997 , 0 150px #A1F997;
border-top: 1em solid white;
padding: 0.5em;
margin-top: 151px;
height: 450px;}
```

try it now

Comment: Thanks, but simply adding a margin-top of 151px is neither dynamic nor a proper solution. I updated the codepen with your code and it wiped out everything. See here:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myLdLL

Comment: You're right, except the boxes are NOT the same height anymore. See here:  http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/screenshot2.png   Perhaps its just me... can you offer a solution?

Comment: Simple. The length of demo 2 is 486px while the others are 450px, manually equalize them one by one.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. The length of "demo 2" is 486px? Do you mean the height of one of my divs (green boxes) is 486px and the others are 450px?   I don't see either of these numbers in my CSS code. Apologize for my noobiness

Comment: All you need to do is add height: 450px under where margin-top:151px is. Look at the code above again.

Comment: Thanks Sebz, I changed what you said, and tried adding one more div to see what happens and it's screwed up the last row of divs! See here:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwRKJK  and here's the same problem on my server
Screenshot:  http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/screenshot3.png . What's going on??

Comment: The height of the div was set to 3000px, that was too short. Always change the height according to how much content you have. I set it to 4000px but thats your personal preference. Look at the code again.

Comment: I've changed height to 4000px, but that doesn't change anything in the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJqWQN
Perhaps it has to do with the CSS selector (identified by bobdye below)

Comment: Ok, I assumed it was bottom row being cut off based on the screenshot, because again everything works fine on my end. When you say "screwed up" that doesn't explain what exactly is happening. Please be more specific not only for me but for other potential helpers as well.

Comment: Sorry about that. This codepen works fine for you? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJqWQN    The problem I'm seeing is that the last 3 divs are out of alignment. Two of them are centered in the row, and the third one is pushed to the row beneath them. Here's a screenshot showing the issue I'm seeing (the bottom div is NOT cut off, just the screenshot is)  http://jasoncampbell.net46.net/public/screenshot3.png

Comment: Remove - margin-right:calc(25% + 1.7em); - Which is line 71.

Comment: You my friend, have been wonderful! Thanks for your persistent help. Solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your website has one more box than your Codepen example, so the CSS selector:

```
.mainbox a:last-of-type:nth-child(4n){
   margin-right:calc(25% + 1.7em);
   box-shadow: 0 50px 0 #A1F997 , 0 100px #A1F997  , 0 150px #A1F997,  100px 0 white,  200px 0 white,  300px 0 white,  400px 0 white
}
```

is taking effect and giving the last box a large right margin, which forces it to the next line.

Comment: Ok, but I might end up having 50 boxes on my site. How can I adapt my code so this error never occurs?

Comment: Well, if you remove the big right margin is should work. What are you trying to do with that particular rule?